# run nodejs in sublime text but failed

Tags: node.js, sublimetext2

I follow the second way shown at

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Javascript-Console-in-Sublime-Text

to run nodejs file test.js in sumblime text.

test.js

```
console.log ("helloworld");
```

it reported

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'node', u'/Users/myname/Documents/test.js']]
[dir:  /Users/myname/Documents]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

it looks like sublime can not run node correctly

Your comment welcome

Comment: Is your code really at /Users/myname/Documents/test.js?

Comment: I run on terminal with command "node /Users/myname/Documents/test.js". it worked

Comment: What is the OS? Did you tried node.js or jsc method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `node` executable file cannot be found by the build system, as it does not reside in any of the directories listed in `path` in the error message. To fix this, open Terminal and run

```
which node
```

to find out where the executable is. Copy the full path, then open the `.sublime-build` file you made and insert the full path to `node`. For example, if `which node` returns `/usr/local/bin/node`, then your `.sublime-build` file should look like this:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/node", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.js"
}
```